Newbie requests advice on Mac Mini or iMac (peripherals - keyboard, mouse, monitors)
I'm mostly a PC user but would like to get an Apple to play with (programming for iPhone, web programming, other programming play).The new Mac Minis came out and start at about $600.  However, I'm confused as to what peripherals I need and if they must be Apple peripherals (very expensive!).  Presumably, I need monitor(s) (can I hook up 2), keyboard, mouse.
If I need to get Apple peripherals, or the alternatives are also expensive, would I be better off just getting an iMac (24 inch screen built in).
I don't need a laptop. The computer can stay in one place. If however, the laptop is as powerful and as cheap as the mac mini and/or imac, that would be good to know.
I have monitors that I hook up to my PC via HDMI. Will those work?  Can I use PC keyboards/mouse?  If not, are there Apple compatible keyboards/mouse that are cheaper than Apple's offering?

For a mac mini you do not need any Apple peripherals.
You can use the ones you already have for a Windows PC.
I am typing this on a 2020 Mac mini (I also had a 2009 one) with a Corsair keyboard, Dell monitor, Contour uni mouse. (The keyboard and mouse are more expensive than Apple versions not everything Apple is expensive)
The only thing that might differ between a Mac and a Windows setup is the keyboard - mac and Windows do have different keys or at leat position of keys, but you can choose in the macOS setup the Windows key mapping.

I would say, the iMac is a high quality display with a free computer at a first approximation. If you aren’t going to use the mini with a 4K display or better, get the iMac. The new M4 portables are as powerful as the M4 or M4 Pro, but you spend a lot more $$ for that if you don’t need or value portability.
Everything you have for USB accessories will connect to either choice as Apple went away from custom connectors along with the transition from PowerPC to Intel in 2006. Just watch for old scanners or printers as driver support can be problematic. Storage, keyboards and mice are highly compatible.

The only big issue that isn’t solvable for people that I see is some displays exist in a very bad physical size to pixel count (PPI) range and if you are doing text based work, you might hate that display on any Mac.

What external monitor and size combinations provide best scaling on macOS?
Which external monitor to choose for MacBook?

Everything else you can change: cables, keyboard mapping, shortcuts, your brain and scroll direction, UI changes, finding software that works in both OS ecosystems.

What is this to do with mac mini as the OP asked. Also the iMac is not a monitor with a computer - since 2012 our before - with a monitor you would be able to use it with the replacement computer you buy in several years time. Unfortunately modern iMacs do not allow itself to act as a pure monitor.

This is my advice @mmmmmm they indicated they’re not sure they can use a display with their Mac and if they get a mini, they really need to think about a 4k display in my opinion. Let me edit that up top in case my answer was too subtle. Just because a HDMI display will connect, that’s not going to mean they’re happy  with it.

I am quite happy with a 1920 × 1080 HDMI display :)

Awesome, @mmmmmm what’s the PPI on that? 81.6 like the Samsung in the image or more dense?
